# Hibernate change alias in @Formula

Tags: java, hibernate, formula, alias

I have a field:

```
@Formula(value = "(select max(crm_kk_rejestr.data_otrzymania) " +
                   "from crm_kk_rejestr " + 
                   "where crm_kk_rejestr.idkntrh = idkntrh)")
private Date dataOtrzymania;
```

I want sorted by this field, but I get an error:

```
ORDER BY column or expression must be in SELECT list in this context.
```

Comment: What is the generated query? If you dont see it, you need to enable hibernate query logging in the configs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution (SQL Server), f.e.:

```
private String yourFieldForAlias;

@Formula("( validSQLquery ) as 'yourOwnAlias', NULL")
public String getYourFieldForAlias() {
  return yourFieldForAlias;
}
```

The generated query will be:

```
....
 ( validSQLquery ) as 'yourOwnAlias', null as formula0_0_
....
```

and you need just to:

```
order by yourOwnAlias
```

[hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate)[annotation](/questions/tagged/annotation)[formula](/questions/tagged/formula)[custom](/questions/tagged/custom)[alias](/questions/tagged/alias)

Comment: Amazing! It works for me and my mom. Use `validSQLquery` instead of `NULL` to populate `yourFieldForAlias` with the computed value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FIRST 50 {...}


  (SELECT max(crm_kk_rejestr.data_otrzymania)
   FROM crm_kk_rejestr
   WHERE crm_kk_rejestr.idkntrh = kontrahent0_.idkntrh) AS formula62_,
             kontrahent0_.nazwa1 || ' ' || kontrahent0_.nazwa2 AS formula63_
FROM kontrahent0 kontrahent0_
ORDER BY
  (SELECT max(crm_kk_rejestr.data_otrzymania)
   FROM crm_kk_rejestr
   WHERE crm_kk_rejestr.idkntrh = kontrahent0_.idkntrh) DESC
```

Its not work because this is subselect. If i change subselect to alias "formula62_" all work good.

Its possible change alias to my custom in hibernate?